# I'm doing well. But some particles seem not to fit. What's the role of "こと" in this sentence?

Tags: particles

そっか。みなさん、どなたか木村さんのことしりませんか。

Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

It means "About".

"Is that so? Does any of you guys know *about* Mr.Kimura?"

Whenever Koto comes after a name,likely it'll stand for "about (the person)".